# How create new Scala Map class?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In Scala I want to create a generic new `Map` class called `MyClass`. In this class i want to maintain the generality of types and modify only method ++ for Sequence type.
The ++ method must merge the equal object for the same key in this map.

Example

```
val map1 = ("a"->Seq(1,2))
val map2 = ("a"->Seq(2,3))
```

the result must be

```
map1++map2 = ("a"->Seq(1,2,3))
```

and not

```
map1++map2 = ("a"->Seq(2,3))
```

For all other type `MyMap` must be the same of "classic" Map class.

Comment: Go on then. What's stopping you? (aka what have you tried and where are you stuck?)

Comment: Just extend `Map` an override the `++` method.

Comment: I have problem on type parameter: always show me "Map class take type parameter" though i insert generic type (a:T, b:R).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, you should try something first and then come back if you encounter some specific problem. Here's how you can start, given that you want to implement the Map trait:

```
class MyClass[A, +B] extends Map[A, B] {

  def get(key: A): Option[B] = ???
  def iterator: Iterator[(A, B)] = ???
  def +[B1 >: B](kv: scala.Tuple2[A, B1]): Map[A, B1] = ???
  def -(key: A): Map[A, B] = ???

  override def ++[B1 >: B](xs: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[scala.Tuple2[A, B1]]) = ???

}
```

You can also start from an existing Map implementation, such as

```
class MyClass[A, +B] extends scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[A, B] {

  override def ++[B1 >: B](xs: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[scala.Tuple2[A, B1]]) = ???

}
```

However, in that case compiler will warn you that inheritance from existing implementation is unwise because of implementation details.